# capture spaced user input

Tags: user-input, go

I am trying to capture user input in Go with little luck. I can get non-spaced words to work:

```
var s string
println("enter string:")
fmt.Scan(&s)
```

However, the Go documentation says that scan will delimit at spaces and new lines. So I think I have to set up bufio.Reader's ReadLine. Here is my attempt, which will not compile:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

const delim = '\n'
const file = "file"

func main() {

    r := bufio.NewReader() *Reader

    println("enter string:")
    line, err := r.ReadString(delim)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(line)

}
```

errors:

```
1.go:14: not enough arguments in call to bufio.NewReader
1.go:14: undefined: Reader
```

So, how do I define "Reader"? And if it was defined, would this be the correct way to capture the input as a string, delimited at "\n", and not at the space? Or should I be doing something completely different?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
r := bufio.NewReader() *Reader
```

to read

```
r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
```

to fix the problem.

The original encantation is incorrect because you seem to just copied and pasted the method's signature from [the spec](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/), but the spec defines the signature, not an example of a call, so `*Reader` in there is the method's return type (the type your variable `r` will have).  And the method's sole argument is defined to be `rd io.Reader`; that interface is conveniently implemented by the `os.Stdin` symbol which seems like a perfect match for your task.

P.S.
Consider reading all the docs in the ["Learning Go"](http://golang.org/doc/docs.html) documentation section, especially "Effective Go".

Comment: thanks, this worked great. i have read the docs, just having some trouble wrapping my head around some concepts :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for `bufio.NewReader`, it takes an argument of type `io.Reader` (which makes sense, because it takes a normal reader and makes it buffered, similar to `java.io.BufferedReader` in Java, which also takes a `Reader` argument). What is `io.Reader`? Looking at its documentation, it is an interface, specifying anything that has a `Read` method. Many types have a `Read` method; most commonly, `*os.File`. So you can construct a `File` using `os.Open` etc.

```
f, _ := os.Open(file)
r := bufio.NewReader(f)
```